# Why do my "native" windows 8 apps seem to be running a different color profile?

Tags: windows-8, colors

I just got a brand new ASUS Transformer Book T100TA-C1-GR

Everything is working great, but for some reason native apps like Outlook and People are running the wrong color profile.

If I'm looking at office, or the desktop, and there's a white background, I see a nice pure white and vibrant colors.

If I then switch over to Outlook (ALT + TAB), the app initially looks great, but after a second or so, the white background switches over to some ugly faded yellow, and other colors look washed out.

I tried running through these steps:
http://optimwise.com/fix-windows-photo-viewer-yellow-tint-background/

and then restarted the device.

It's still tinted yellow...

Any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under the default ASUS installed programs, there is one called *Reading Mode*. It changes the hue to that yellow/sepia color for Mail, News, and Reader. You can add others, but I hate it, and have removed those applications from this feature.

Comment: thank you so much!!!! that was driving me insane. I wrote an email to ASUS and they said I should reinstall windows and reset the device to factory default.... It's extremely frustrating that they would suggest something so inane when it's their own bloatware causing the problem